# Hibernate Criteria API join through id

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

when using Criteria API, in order to add filters to an entity referenced by the current one, I use this code:

```
criteria.createAlias("customer", "customer", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);
```

where customer is the customer entity property in the entity which the criteria was created for. problem is, I need to remove the referenced entity and leave only it's id in the class, i.e. replace

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_CUSTOMER")
private CustomerEntity customer;
```

by

```
@Column(name = "ID_CUSTOMER")
private Long customerId;
```

so, what change do I need to make in my criteria alias in order to keep it working? This is a filter example I have on it, along with the join above:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("customer.statusId", statusId));
```

Comment: Why do you *need* to remove the mapping?  The entire point of using hibernate is to be able to map real object relationships :)  You cannot join on an unmapped relationship, you will need to use a subquery.

Comment: I see your point and I agree with it, but this is a request. Every database change is done through a batch request, and the batch execution triggers the lazy initialization of those entities, which slows down the process.

Comment: If the problem is the initialization of customer, you can set the fetch mode to lazy. See the ManyToOne annotation API.